# Unable to query for default vendor from RPM: Error while executing process. while running streamsets

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, rpm-maven-plugin, streamsets

I just followed the following tutorials for latest streamset 2.6.6 with flume as datacollector, https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector/blob/master/BUILD.md

At the time of making the build i have faced the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.2:attached-rpm
>   (generate-sdc-streamsets-datacollector-aws-lib-rpm) on project
>   streamsets-datacollector-aws-lib: Unable to query for default vendor
>   from RPM: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "rpm":
>   error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

Comment: What OS are you on?